# 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header' Error when fetching data from Deezer API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, restful-authentication

I'm creating a React application that fetches data from [Deezer Api](https://developers.deezer.com/api)

Currently, I'm trying to get top albums https://api.deezer.com/chart/0/tracks :

I created a function that requests the data

```
fetchTopAlbums = () => {
    return fetch('https://api.deezer.com/chart/0/tracks', { 'Accept': 'application/json', })
      .then((res) => res.json())
  }
```

On calling this function I get this error in the console

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.deezer.com/chart/0/tracks' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

[image: Error Image can be accessed here]

Comment: why don't you do your research on what cors is.

Comment: you need to add cors to your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deezer api is restricting API calls made from websites. It does this to specifically block what you are trying to do. In general this is the purpose of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to stop unexpected websites from accessing other websites backends. Some services allow any site to access them other ones require you to access that service via a backend between your side and the API in question.

Comment: Okay I believe I understand that quite better now. Thank you